# Angle between two vectors given magnitudes and difference in magnitude

Tags: vectors, mathematical-physics

> Given: **|a|** = 31 , **|b|** = 23 and **|a – b|** = 42 , what is the angle between **a** and **b** and the magnitude of **|a + b**|

How would you solve this, and what kind of diagrams can I use to solve this question?

Edit: I got 78.92 as the angle between |a| and |b|. I got 34.87 as the magnitude of |a + b|

Comment: Do you know the law of cosines?

Comment: Hi Fireblaze. I just tried GEdgar's suggestion, and I think it works. Can you try it and write it up in an edit? We can check your answer. Step 1 is find the angle.

Comment: I got 78.92 as the angle between |a| and |b|. I got 34.87 as the magnitude of |a + b|

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $|\textbf{a} + \textbf{b}|$ is correct. For angle between $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$, it should be $\gt 90^0$ as $\cos\theta$ is negative. I think you missed the negative sign in your working.

$|\textbf{a} - \textbf{b}|^2 = |\textbf{a}|^2 + |\textbf{b}|^2 - 2 \ \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b} \implies \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b} = \frac{1}{2} (31^2 + 23^2 - 42^2) = -137$

So $|\textbf{a} + \textbf{b}|^2 = |\textbf{a}|^2 + |\textbf{b}|^2 + 2 \ \textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b} = 31^2 + 23^2 - 274  = 1216$

$\implies |\textbf{a} + \textbf{b}| = 8 \sqrt{19}$

For angle between $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$,

$\textbf{a} \cdot \textbf{b} = |a| \ |b| \cos\theta \implies \cos\theta = \displaystyle \small - \frac{137}{713}$

$\implies \theta \approx 101.1^0 $

Comment: or about $1.764145>\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians. (So many wrong answers are due to not considering domain, range of $\arccos$, $\arcsin$, etc.)